# Use Adobe Photoshop Plugin in DotNet

Tags: .net, plugins, image-processing, photoshop, managed

I'm good in DotNet. But - I am not good enough in C++ to use Adobe's [SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk.html). My question is, how to make my application (in DotNet) compatible to Photoshop Plugins. It would be cool if I can use Photoshop Plugins to change images.

Regards